# how can I infer type or gurad type of the interface property from another property value?

Tags: typescript-typings

if I have the following interface:

```
export interface IFilterConfig<T>{
//...
readonly predicates: Record<string,(value:T)=> boolean>;
readonly defaultOperation: keyof predicates!! // here is the question
}
```

I tried many possibilites like:
export interface IFilterConfig<T, P extends <Record<string,(value:T)=> boolean>>>{
//...
readonly predicates: P;
readonly defaultOperation: keyof P
}

I want to guard the implementation of this interface

```
export class SomeClass implements IFilterConfig<string>
{
predicates = {
key1:(data:string)=> false,
key2:(data:string)=> true,
}
defaultOperation ='key1'; //is ok.
defaultOperation ='key3'; //is not ok becuase it is not in predicates keys but
defaultOperation here is string so it will accept any string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on the level of the types you can use generics to constrain multiple properties of a type object.

You already have a generic `T` to constrain value arguments. You can add another generic `P` to be used for the keys of the predicate record. So the interface becomes

```
interface IFilterConfig<T, P extends PropertyKey> {
  readonly predicates: Record<P, (value: T) => boolean>;
  readonly defaultOperation: P;
}
```

The generic `P` extends `PropertyKey` since all object properties must be assignable to it. For the moment we have also assigned `P` as the type for `defaultOperation`. This works but does not provide a way to assign a more specific type to represent the default operation's exact type. For example

```
type ConfigA = IFilterConfig<number, 'key1'|'key2'>
```

which corresponds to

```
{
  readonly predicates: Record<"key1" | "key2", (value: number) => boolean>;
  readonly defaultOperation: "key1" | "key2";
}
```

is correct but it could be better to have the default operation type constrained by another generic that itself extends `P`.

```
interface IFilterConfig<T, P extends PropertyKey, D extends P> {
  readonly predicates: Record<P, (value: T) => boolean>;
  readonly defaultOperation: D;
}
```

which gives the type

```
{
  readonly predicates: Record<"key1" | "key2", (value: number) => boolean>;
  readonly defaultOperation: "key1";
}
```

for generics `number`, `"key1"|"key2"`  and `"key1"`.

As for the implementation, I don't know much about how classes work so the best I could get is

```
class SomeClass implements IFilterConfig<string, "key1" | "key2", "key1"> {
  predicates = {
    key1: (data: string) => false,
    key2: (data: string) => true,
  };
  defaultOperation = "key1"
}
```

which works but is not ideal as you have to explicitly type the generics. You can try and make the class Generic like

```
SomeClass<T, P extends PropertyKey, D extends P> implements IFilterConfig<T,P,D>
```

but I was not able to get it working.

If you want to try using functions you can do

```
type FilterConfig<V, P extends PropertyKey, D extends P> = {
  readonly predicates: Record<P, (value: V) => boolean>;
  readonly defaultOperation: D;
};

const createFilterConfig = <V, const P extends PropertyKey, D extends P>(
  config: FilterConfig<V, P, D>,
) => config;

const config = createFilterConfig({
  predicates: {
    key1: (data: string) => false,
    key2: (data: string) => true,
  },
  defaultOperation: "key1",
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Unfortunately I can't use function in my case, it should be some contract (abstract class or interface), I already have a run time validation before using this parameter to ensure defaultIoeration in predicates collection. I was wondering if I can guard it at developping time also.